# How can I solve this exception in the tSalesforceOutputBulkExec Talend component

Tags: java, salesforce, talend, wsc

I've recently upgraded to ODI 5.5.1 and Java 1.7. Since doing so I have not been able to perform bulk processes into salesforce using tSalesforceOutputBulkExec.
I consistently get the following exception message when attempting to run jobs.

```
Starting job TestBulk at 10:50 13/08/2014.

[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3438
[statistics] connected
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.sforce.async.BatchRequest.loadBatchInfo(Ljava/io/InputStream;)Lcom/sforce/async/BatchInfo; from class com.sforce.async.BulkConnection
    at com.sforce.async.BulkConnection.createBatchFromStreamImpl(BulkConnection.java:154)
    at com.sforce.async.BulkConnection.createBatchFromStream(BulkConnection.java:131)
    at org.talend.salesforceBulk.SalesforceBulkAPI.createBatch(SalesforceBulkAPI.java:369)
    at org.talend.salesforceBulk.SalesforceBulkAPI.createBatchesFromCSVFile(SalesforceBulkAPI.java:355)
    at org.talend.salesforceBulk.SalesforceBulkAPI.executeBulk(SalesforceBulkAPI.java:122)
    at prototyping.testbulk_0_1.TestBulk.tSalesforceInput_1Process(TestBulk.java:2180)
    at prototyping.testbulk_0_1.TestBulk.runJobInTOS(TestBulk.java:2522)
    at prototyping.testbulk_0_1.TestBulk.main(TestBulk.java:2368)
[statistics] disconnected
Job TestBulk ended at 10:50 13/08/2014. [exit code=1]
```

The exception appears to be occurring in the  wsc.jar provided as part of the talend build but which comes from an open source package provided by salesforce and hosted on https://code.google.com/p/sfdc-wsc/downloads/list

I'm not sure though whether the problem I'm seeing is in the wsc jar or within my setup.
Has anyone else seen or solved this problem?
Should I replace the wsc.jar file and if so is this the correct jar to replace OS_DI-Win32-r118616-V5.5.1\plugins\org.talend.designer.components.localprovider_5.5.1.r118616\components\tSalesforceBulkExec\wsc.jar

Comment: You'll probably want to raise this on Talend's (JIRA)[https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TDI] but it can't hurt to try and replace the packaged wsc.jar with one from that Google Code site. Make sure to back the original wsc.jar up first. I don't see any mention of it on there. It looks like the packaged wsc might have that method set as private rather than public but I'm not sure without access to the source for the packaged wsc.jar. The wsc23.jar source from the Google Code site looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks @ydaetskcoR I have raised it on the Talend forum and got no response so I will try JIRA instead.

Comment: Can you post the link back here when you've raised it on JIRA please? Also if it gets resolved by Talend then self answer with the resolution for anyone else with this problem in the future.

Comment: Here is the JIRA link https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TDI-30410 if there is any resolution I'll reflect that here.

Comment: I've had to revert to using 5.4.1 for the time being as I'm still no closer to finding the cause or solution.